# How to Create a Macro that uses Variable Loops to Copy a Sheet then Rename the Copy?

Tags: excel, vba, copy, rename

Trying to create an Macro in MS Excel that loops through a set of names within a master sheet, then creates copies of a template sheet and renames those copies according to the names within the master sheet (excluding names for pre-existing sheets).

I have been able to successfully create a copy of the template sheet, however I have been unsuccessful in renaming the copied sheet.

Below is the code:

```
Sub NewEmployee()

    'Assigns variable types
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim master As Worksheet
    Dim template As Worksheet
    Dim TempCopy As Worksheet
    Dim wsNew As Worksheet
    Dim colB As String
    Dim EmpName As String
    
    'Assigns variable references
    Set master = Worksheets("Master Labor sheet")
    Set template = Worksheets("Timesheet Template")
    
    'Turns off refreshing the spreadsheet
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        
        'References the code below to apply to the Master Labor sheet.
        With master
        
            'Counts each row up until the last row.
            lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
            
            'Loops the code below for each row.
            For i = 1 To lastRow
                
                'Only references cells within Column B of the Master Labor sheet, which consists of employee names.
                colB = master.Cells(i, "B").Value
                
                'Loops the code below for each sheet within the Excel document.
                For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
                    
                    'Filters out specififed cells and pre-existing sheets to not be included in the loop.
                    If colB <> "Name" And colB <> "" And ws.name <> colB And ws.name <> "ICM" And ws.name <> "Latcon" And ws.name <> "Mastor Labor sheet" And ws.name <> "Timesheet Template" Then
                        
                        'Sets the employee name to a new variable intended for the If statement.
                        EmpName = colB
                        
                        'Creates a copy of the Timesheet Template sheet.
                        template.Copy After:=template
                        
                        'Intended to rename the Timesheet Template copy to be the employee name.
                        Worksheets(template.Index + 1).name = EmpName
                        
                        'Intended to set a variable for the newly created and renamed Timesheet Template copy.
                        wsNew = Worksheets(EmpName)
                        
                        'References the code below to apply to the newly created and renamed Timesheet Template copy.
                        With wsNew
                            
                            'Intended to input the name of the employee in the header cell of the Timesheet Template copy.
                            Set Range("B1").Value = EmpName
                        
                        End With
                        
                        'Intended to exit the "For Each ws" loop to go back to the "For i" loop.
                        Exit For
                    
                    End If
                Next
            Next
        End With
    
    'Turns on refreshing the spreadsheet.
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

At the line shown below, I get "Error 1004 – That name is already taken. Try a different one.”
`Worksheets(template.Index + 1).name = EmpName`

Not sure what I am doing wrong here...

Comment: You need to double check the logic where you check if the worksheet name exists. At the moment it only looks at the current sheet that it's on during the loop before proceeding to create the sheet. Instead you'll need to check all the sheets before you create the sheet. That's why you're getting the "That name is already taken" error

Comment: @Kairu How would one go about comparing a list of employee names from a worksheet (i.e. Master Labor sheet, Column B) to check whether that worksheet exists within the workbook? Would I not use a loop?

Comment: You could add a boolean to check if the worksheet was found in the loop. Something like ’For each ws if ws.name = colB then found = true’ and then skip that colB if found

Answer (score 0):

```
Option Explicit

Sub CopySheets()
    Dim wbSource As Workbook
    Set wbSource = ThisWorkbook
    
    Dim wsMaster As Worksheet
    Set wsMaster = wbSource.Worksheets("Master Labor sheet")
    
    Dim wsTemplate As Worksheet
    Set wsTemplate = wbSource.Worksheets("Timesheet Template")
    
    Dim lastRow As Long
    lastRow = wsMaster.Cells(wsMaster.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
    
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 1 To lastRow
        Dim sheetname As String
        sheetname = wsMaster.Cells(i, "B").Value
        
        If Len(sheetname) > 0 And Not SheetExists(sheetname) Then
            wsTemplate.Copy After:=wbSource.Sheets(wbSource.Sheets.Count)
            ActiveSheet.Name = sheetname
        End If
    Next i

End Sub

Function SheetExists(sheetname As String) As Boolean
Dim sh As Worksheet
    SheetExists = False
    For Each sh In Worksheets
        If sh.Name = sheetname Then
            SheetExists = True
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next sh
End Function
```

Comment: Tried the code. No error codes, but it didn't do anything.

Comment: Here is a screenshot link to give an idea of what the Master Labor sheet looks like (confidential info blurred of course): [Master Labor sheet screenshot](https://i.imgur.com/gpMHxwq.jpg)

Comment: @JoshBerry the sheet names are in column B of master labor sheet right? if the values in column B are already existing as sheet names it will not create the template sheets anymore, also since you have a header use `For i = 2 To lastRow`